# Отправка формы зависимого списка

Tags: javascript, html, php7

Я создал форму с зависимыми списками, но при нажатии submit отправляется только значание для submit, а требуется отправить значения из выбранных полей select>option. Подскажите пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка?

```html
<head>
    
    <style type="text/css">
    
    html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,progress,video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden],template{display:none}a{background:transparent}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:700}dfn{font-style:italic}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-.5em}sub{bottom:-.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:1em 40px}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}pre{overflow:auto}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}button{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}input{line-height:normal}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto}optgroup{font-weight:700}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0}
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
        text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
</head>
    <form id="part_add" action = 'errorDescription.php' method = 'post' >
<body style="font-size: 14px; position: relative; padding: 15px 20px;">
    <table class="table" id="dynamicApp">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Тип прибора</th>
            <th>Серийный номер прибора</th>
            <th>Номер ошибки</th>           
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            
    <td>
        <select class="form__field-input" placeholder="Выберите тип прибора" v-model="select_device_type" @change="fetchSerialNumber">

            <option v-for="data in devises_data" :value="data.id">{{ data.type_name }}</option>
        
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form__field-input" placeholder="Выберите серийный номер" v-model="select_serial_number" @change="fetchCondition">
        
            <option v-for="data in serial_number_data" :value="data.id">{{ data.serial_number }}</option>
            
        </select>
    </td>

    <td>
        <select class="form__field-input" placeholder="Выберите номер ошибки" v-model="select_condition">
        
            <option v-for="data in condition_data" :value="data.id">{{ data.condition }}</option>
            
        </select>

    </td>           
        </tr>       
    </tbody>

</table>

        <input type = 'submit'  name = 'send' value = 'Исправить ошибку' class="tm-user-menu__auth-button tm-user-menu__auth-button_primary"/>
    </form>
      
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>

var application = new Vue({
 el:'#dynamicApp',
 data:{
  select_device_type:'',
  devises_data:'',
  select_serial_number:'',
  serial_number_data:'',
  select_condition:'',
  condition_data:''
 },
 methods:{
  fetchDevicesType:function(){
   axios.post("SearchByError.php", {
    request_for:'device_type'
   }).then(function(response){
    application.devises_data = response.data;
    application.select_serial_number = '';
    application.serial_number_data = '';
    application.select_condition = '';
    application.condition_data = '';
   });
  },
  fetchSerialNumber:function(){
   axios.post("SearchByError.php", {
    request_for:'devices',
    id:this.select_device_type
   }).then(function(response){
    application.serial_number_data = response.data;
    application.select_serial_number = '';
    application.select_condition = '';
    application.condition_data = '';
   });
  },
  fetchCondition:function(){
   axios.post("SearchByError.php", {
    request_for:'rules', 
    id:this.select_serial_number
   }).then(function(response){
    application.condition_data = response.data;
    application.select_condition = '';
   });
  }
 },
 created:function(){
  this.fetchDevicesType();
 }
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.ls input {
    color: #edf0f1;
}
.table{
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.table td{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    text-align: left;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
    background: #fff;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(even){
    background: #F7F7F7;
}


.tm-user-menu__auth-button {
    border: 1px solid #548eaa;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #548eaa;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1rem;
    margin-right: 12px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tm-user-menu__auth-button_primary {
    background-color: #548eaa;
    color: #fff;
}

:lang(ru) {
    quotes: "\AB" "\BB";
}

.form__field-input{
width:100%;
height:40px;
background:#FFF;
border:1px solid #DBDBDB;
padding:0 14px;
box-sizing:border-box;
font-size:12px;
font-family:"-apple-system",BlinkMacSystemFont,Arial,sans-serif;
color:#333
}
</style>
</body>
```

Comment: Может я не прав, но каждому селекту надо имя указать..

Comment: Как-то режет глаз то, что `form`у вас открывается ещё до `body`.

Comment: @Quazimorda а закрывается до `body`

Comment: @nazarpunk в приведённом примере это правило выполнено.

Comment: Сергей Махнёв большое спасибо! Добавил имена плюс убрал стили указанные в верху, открыл форму после body и получил через POST имена селектов со значениями.